# Why does this not work to configure node using nvm and yarn on remote VM?

Tags: node.js, bash, ssh, nvm

I am trying to automate VM configuration with a script and am having some trouble getting access to some path variables that get set in either `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, or `~/.profile`.

My remote VM is running ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I am deploying over ssh.

This is the array that gets joined together to be run as a bash command to configure the vm by installing nvm:

return [
      `rm -rf ~/.nvm`,
      `sudo apt-get update`,
      `sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev`,
      `curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh`,
      `bash install_nvm.sh`,
      `echo "source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh" >> ~/.bash_profile`
    ].join('\n');

```js
return [
      `rm -rf ~/.nvm`,
      `sudo apt-get update`,
      `sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev`,
      `curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh`,
      `bash install_nvm.sh`,
      `echo "source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh" >> ~/.bash_profile`
    ].join('\n');
```

But when when I run the next script that actually installs node and yarn, it cannot find `nvm`:

```js
return [
      `nvm install ${config.node.version}`,
      `nvm use ${config.node.version}`,
      `echo "using node $(node -v) and npm $(npm -v)"`,
      `curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash`,
      'echo "export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$PATH"" >> ~/.bash_profile',
    ].join('\n');
```

This is the error:
    bash: nvm: command not found

```
bash: line 1: nvm: command not found`
```

I don't want to ssh in and manually add anything to any of the various profiles. I'd like it all to be done by the script. I also want to avoid sourcing `~/.nvm/nvm.sh` or sourcing any of the profiles when the ssh session begins. I was under the impression that an ssh session automatically sources `~/.bash_profile`, which should then read from those variables correct? If not, then how else can I configure my deployment script to automatically have access to these variables?

Comment: Have you already confirmed that `nvm` is installed by the time the second set of commands is run? Just want to be sure it _should_ exist. Also, for the user you are shelling in as have you made sure the user's shell is set to `/bin/bash` instead of something like `/bin/sh`?

Comment: so the second command runs as an && after the first script (the node process exits with 0 from the first script), so it should already be installed. As for the user shel, how would I confirm?

Comment: Also why does that even matter?

Comment: It matters because it may not have what is needed in the path. You are having it source `~/.nvm/nvm.sh` from within your `.bash_profile` script.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that you are using && as you said in your comments I would add a line to actually `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` before running the `nvm` commands. You likely don't have the command available at the shell until that has been run.

Change this:

```js
return [
      `rm -rf ~/.nvm`,
      `sudo apt-get update`,
      `sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev`,
      `curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh`,
      `bash install_nvm.sh`,
      `echo "source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh" >> ~/.bash_profile`
    ].join('\n');
```

To this:

```js
return [
      `rm -rf ~/.nvm`,
      `sudo apt-get update`,
      `sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev`,
      `curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh`,
      `bash install_nvm.sh`,
      `echo "source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh" >> ~/.bash_profile`,
      `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`
    ].join('\n');
```

Comment: I know that sourcing the nvm executable will give me access to it. I wanted to write a script where I didn't need to do that though, the same way I don't have to when i locally use nvm